# command line to suspend windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, suspend

I'd like to suspend my windows machine after a specified time like

```
shutdown -s -t 3600
```

but I don't want to turn it off, but only switch to suspend mode. Is there a command line to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `at` command, running the command to put the computer to sleep. The `shutdown`command doesn't have a sleep parameter.

`at <time> rundll32 powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState`

you'll find more information about `at` and its parameters [**here**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313565).

Instead of the `rundll32`command, you could use an alternative command-line program, like [**sleep.exe**](http://www.gammadyne.com/cmdline.htm#sleep) for instance.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about sleep.exe, had totally forgotten about this little gem.

Comment: Hmmm. Very good! But "at" command works only with admin privileges...... :(